# Can "grep" find regex match in strings? or will it only search through files?

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a shell script to look for a pattern in strings. Will "grep" search strings? or will it only search in files?

```
# does this work and will grep find the pattern?
line="INSERT INTO something VALUES('v1',v2','UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED',1,'v3','2023-07-15 23:36:53.0')"
val=$(grep -Ec --regexp='INSERT INTO something*[UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED, UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED].*[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]' --file=$line)
echo "$val"
```

If not, how do I search for a pattern (using regex) in a string in shell script? The thing is, I am iterating line-by-line in file which is why I am searching a line. I only have to modify specific lines.

Comment: Instead of `--file=$line` use `<<< "$line"`

Comment: I've never seen `--regexp=` nor `--file=` in 40+ years of using `grep`. You could just do `grep -Ecf 'file' 'regexp'`. Your use of `-E` along with escaping `{` and `}` are canceling each other out btw. Get your grep command working on it's own first and then worry about applying it to a string and capturing it's output.

Comment: You can, but it's a bit pointless, since bash has already a builtin-way to match a string against a regex. `grep` would be handy only if you, for instance, really need the `-P` option of _grep_, which is more powerful than the extended regex implemented in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a here string:

```
# does this work and will grep find the pattern?
line="INSERT INTO something VALUES('v1',v2','UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED',1,'v3','2023-07-15 23:36:53.0')"
val=$(grep -Ec --regexp='INSERT INTO something*[UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED, UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED].*[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]' <<<"$line")
echo "$val"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Diego, what is that operator "<<<"? is there some documentation for it?

Comment: See [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)

Answer (score 2):

### Bash pattern matching

Bash (and Zsh) [can do regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b) directly with `[[ "input" =~ pattern ]]`.

I propose to always put the pattern in a variable. Avoids quoting headaches around the pattern.

For your example

```
line="INSERT INTO something VALUES('v1',v2','UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED',1,'v3','2023-07-15 23:36:53.0')"
pattern='INSERT INTO something.*[UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED, UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED].*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9])'
if [[ "$line" =~ $pattern ]]; then
  echo "match"
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "no match"
fi
```

The missing quotes around the `$pattern` are intentional and significant. A regex pattern in Bash is parsed special and need no quotes even if it has spaces.
Also I had to slightly adapt your initial regex. A missing dot before the first '*' and removed the backslashes around the {}.

A **major benefit** of doing regex directly with Bash (apart from the performance benefit of not having to fork an external command) is that you can use capture groups!
When the pattern matches Bash will set a special array [BASH_REMATCH](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) where the first element is the entire patched string and each other element is a matched capture group.
(for Zsh this is a bit different. See the array [match](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell) or the [shell option](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-bash_002c-BASH_005fREMATCH-variable) to emulate Bash's behavior)

### Process substitution

Also an alternative to herestrings if you want to use grep is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) `<( command )`. Roughly: execute command and provide the output as if it was a file.

```
line="INSERT INTO something VALUES('v1',v2','UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED',1,'v3','2023-07-15 23:36:53.0')"
val=$(grep -Ec --regexp='INSERT INTO something*[UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED, UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED].*[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]' <(echo "$line"))
echo "$val"
```

And if you only want to know if the grep matches or not (which the `-c` indicates since there is max 1 line here) you can also place it in an if:

```
if grep --silent -E pattern file; then
  echo match
fi
```

---

Also while we're at it: the regex part `[UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED, UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED]` doesn't do what you would expect. It appears as if it should match either `UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED` or `UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED`. But `[...]` is a character class. It matches any of the characters in the class. So this part of the regex matches one character which is any of the upper case letters in those two words, or a underscore or a comma or a space.

To match either of some alternatives you can use `(UPLOAD_REQUEST_RESULTS_DOWNLOADED|UPLOAD_REQUEST_CANCELLED)`.